# Resume Activiti task from Camel ActiveMQ route

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, activiti

I'm trying to send a message from an Activiti Camel task to an ActiveMQ queue, which should resume the activity when it is received by Camel. As I understand it, when the message is received from the queue lacks the properties that would enable it to be identified by Camel in order to be routed to the correct activity task.

As such a `Business key is Null` Exception is raised and the route fails.

```
from("activiti:SampleProcess:myCamelTask")
 .to("activemq:queue:myQueue");
```

As expected, if I hardcode either the `PROCESS_ID_PROPERTY` or the `PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY` in the receiving route, the message is routed correctly (when the ID matches).

```
from("activemq:queue:myQueue")
  .setBody(constant("test body"))
  .setProperty(PROCESS_ID_PROPERTY, constant("50"))
// .setProperty(PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY, constant("CUSTOM-KEY"))
.to("activiti:SampleProcess:receiveAsyncPing");
```

How can I get either property in the receiving route so I can set them accordingly?

Or is there a more recommended way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

A good question.
The way I handled this is to inject the PROCESS_KEY within the route using the setProperty() command:

See below where I set the process key (business key) to "bar":

```
from(startProcessEndpoint)
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logMsg3)
  .setProperty("PROCESS_KEY_PROPERTY",foo)
  .setBody(constant("bar"))
.to("activiti:testCamelTask:receive")
```

Now, if you dont want to use a constant, then you have access to the exchange object within the route and can use an Expression as shown below:

```
    Expression foo = new Expression() {
        @Override
        public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> aClass) {
            return (T) "foo";
        }
    };
```

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Greg, thank you for your answer! At that point however, how do you match with the route that sent the original message to ActiveMQ? Also, I got somewhat confused, the business key is set as foo or bar?